# How to import h5py after pyximport.install()

Tags: python, h5py

I am trying to import h5py. It works normally. However when I do pyximport.install()
it stops working. How to get around that?

Example:

```
import pyximport
x = pyximport.install()
import h5py
```

This gives me a long error. Also I cannot do `pyximport.uninstall(*x)` as `pyximport.install()` is done by some other module. Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All errors given relate to HDF 5 C library types. Thus, you will need to find a way to include the C library header files. Some possible solution may be at the [Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#dependency-handling)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. Import h5py before you call pyximport.install, or replace pyximport.install with proper cython compilation at install time.

Long answer:
The pyximport.install is meant to be used for development and testing purposes only. It has some feature for example that it looks for code to compile. Some libraries, like h5py are also using cython, so pyximport.install will try to compile it.
One solution is therefore to import h5py before the call to pyximport.install.

But as I mentioned earlier, pyximport.install is designed for compiling cython code on the fly under the development period. Once the code is more or less stable, this on-th-fly compilation should be replaced by proper compilation at installation time, see for example http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-distutils